# Desktop environment switcher is broken?

Tags: unity, gnome, package-management, plasma

I have Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS, with kubuntu-desktop installed as well as ubuntu-gnome-desktop. The problem is that I cannot switch between Unity, Plasma, and Gnome. When I click the switcher, it does not show any desktop environments and defaults to Gnome. When I try to install Unity, which apparently has been uninstalled, it gives me a "you have held broken packages" error. The login is also quite broken, as it requires multiple tries to log in. In short, I might have irreversibly damaged my computer.

Comment: I have a feeling this is a problem with multiple display managers (lightdm, gdm, kdm etc...) you can try `sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm` (or gdm, etc..) and set a default display manager.

Comment: gdm3 and sddm work for the switcher. It seems that the problem lies with lightdm.

Comment: Glad to hear it, I had a similiar issue and lightdm was my problem too. It doesn't seem to want to play nice with the others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set a different default display manager using

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure lightdm
```

(or gmd3, kdm, sddm, etc...)

Changing the default manager should work to restore the switcher functions. It seems lightdm does not like to play well with others.